# Validating a PL/SQL Stored Procedure OUT REF CURSOR in SQL Developer's Unit Testing framework

Tags: oracle, unit-testing, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am developing a series of PL/SQL Stored Procedures in a package that open REF CURSORs that are passed to the caller as OUT parameters for purposes of interoperability with another framework. I am using SQL Developer and recently started looking into using the testing features built into it.

I am looking for a way to validate the results of a REF CURSOR using SQL Developer's Unit Testing framework. I developed some paging logic, and I want to ensure that it is operating correctly so I was hoping I could verify that I have the correct number of rows and that their row numbers are within the range of the appropriate page.

I found a similar question [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2131008), but that solution renders the unit tests absolutely useless (at least as far as I can tell) because it doesn't actually perform any validation after running the procedure. If someone could explain how to validate it or show me what I'm missing from the solution from Oracle's Forums, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Process Validation can be used to unit test datatypes that SQL Developer cannot handle.

1. Create an implementation and link (synchronize) it with a dummy procedure or function.
2. Set up parameters and results so that the Test completes with a Success
3. Create a Process Validation with 'User Pl/Sql Code' using the template shown

Template:

```
DECLARE
  l_Cursor  SYS_REFCURSOR ;
BEGIN
  OPEN l_Cursor FOR '<SQL goes here>' ;
  MY_PROCEDURE( l_Cursor ) ;
  <do validation>
  CLOSE l_Cursor;
  IF <not valid> THEN
    RAISE PROGRAM_ERROR ;
  END IF ;
END ;
```

Answer (score 1):

We have done something similar in PL/SQL (although not with the Unit Testing Framework of SQL Developer) by comparing the XML representations of two REF CURSORs:

- define a "expected" query that returns your expected output as a REF CURSOR (typically selecting some constants from dual)
- run both your "expected" and your "real" query, and convert their output to XML / HTML / whatever
- compare the output

To convert a REF CURSOR to XML, you can use DBMS_XMLGEN, as shown in [AskTom on describing a ref cursor](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:75558626875490)

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I'm looking specifically for doing it in SQL Developer. I'm really trying to test my paging logic in the SQL statement used for the cursor. I suppose I should update my question to reflect that.